# How do I make a OnClickListener in Java

Tags: java

I used to program with html and to make a alert all I had to do was make an alert("Hello World"); but with java it is much more advanced. I need help to make a button that when someone clicks it, it has an alert message on the screen. This is my code right now:

```
    MyOnClickListener onClickListener = new MyOnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("deleteAtIndex",idx);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();

        }
    };
    for (int i =0;i<buttonList.size();i++) {
        buttonList.get(i).setText("Remove");
        buttonList.get(i).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading java's actionlistener http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html